# openvpn kill switch on linux

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I've not found a tested solution to make kill switch for openvpn tunnel.

This could be works ? I need only lan traffic and not Internet access if vpn not started or goes down.

```
    sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m comment --comment "vpn" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p icmp -m comment --comment "icmp" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -m comment --comment "lan" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1198 -m comment --comment "openvpn" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m comment --comment "ssh" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m comment --comment "ntp" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "dns" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "dns" -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP
```

Comment: And how would this qualify as a kill switch? As your rules just use `eth0` most things (ICMP, SSH, NTP etc.) would work.

Comment: could you suggest me a better way to do it please ?

Comment: Instead of `-o` use `-d` just like your LAN rule? It's not really clear what your setup looks like or what you're trying to achieve. Please try to clarify both things. After that maybe someone would be able to give some real help.